# Three.js Particles of various sizes

Tags: javascript, three.js, particles

I'm new to three.js and am trying to figure out the best way to add a 1000 particles each being a different size and color. The texture for each particle is created by drawing a canvas. By using a ParticleSystem all the particles are the same color and size. Creating a ParticleSystem for each particle is very inefficient. Is there an efficient way to handle this?

Comment: I haven't used Three much, but I'm pretty sure I've seen examples with a single ParticleSystem that has multiple colors.

Comment: Do you have any existing code? I think I know how this can be done.

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_particles2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to go about this, in my experience, is to create a customized shader material; you can then include attributes, which are properties that vary from particle to particle. Your shader code would look something like this:

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 customColor;
attribute float customSize;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() 
{
    vColor = customColor; // set color associated to vertex; use later in fragment shader
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = customSize * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec3 vColor; // colors associated to vertices; assigned by vertex shader
void main() 
{
    // calculates a color for the particle
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1.0 );
    // sets particle texture to desired color
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
}
```

For a similar live example, check out:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ParticleSystem-Attributes.html

Comment: also see the [ShaderParticleEngine](https://github.com/squarefeet/ShaderParticleEngine) based on the work of @lee-stemkoski

Comment: +1: The link in the above comment runs 10x faster due to clever use of the GPU.

Comment: meanwhile, threejs doesnt support material-attributes anymore, they're now in the geometry, and moreover, `Geometry.colors` is a standard array that can be filled, resulting in an attribute `color` passed to the shader.